# CSS Image Hover surprisingly not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover effect that will change the color of the image to blue, as the mouse hovers it. I've already created a class for the images and styled it in my css but its still not working. I've also tried changing z-indexes but to no avail.

```css
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One:400,700);     /*--- Header --*/
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700); /*---    Navigation --*/

    *
    {
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
    }

     body
    {
 background-image: url('../Images/background.png');
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 
    }

    .clearfix
    {
 clear:both;
    }

    #wrapper
    {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1120px;
 overflow: auto;  
 border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #main_header
    {
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Black Ops One', sans-serif;
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
    }

    #main_header h1
    {
 float: left;
 font-size: 380%;
 margin: -10% 0 0 2%;
 
    }

    #callout
    {
 margin: 50px 20px 0 0;
    }

    #callout h2{
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
    }

    #callout p{
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0%;
 color: grey;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    #nav_menu
    {
 
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: white;
    }

    #nav_menu li
    {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px 20px 20px 63px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
    }

    #nav_menu li a
    {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
    }

    #nav_menu li a:hover
    {
 color: grey;
    }

    #content_area 
    {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    }

    .sub-menu
    { 
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 5px;
 display: none;
 z-index: 60;
 border-radius: 15px;
    }

    #nav_menu .sub-menu li a
    {
 color: black;
    }

    #nav_menu li:hover .sub-menu
    {
 display: block;
    }

    #nav_menu li .sub-menu
    {
 width: 16.5%;
    }

    #nav_menu li .sub-menu li
    {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .sub-menu li:hover
    {
 color: green;
 background-color: yellow;
    }

    /*--- Start Image Slider --*/
    .slider{
 max-width: 1100px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
   
    
    }

    .slider1 img{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .slider .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a{
 outline: 0 none;
 position: absolute;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 top: 40%;
 height: 71px;
 width: 40px;
 transition: all 0.7s;
    }

    .slider .bx-wrapper:hover .bx-controls-direction a{
 
    }

    .slider .bx-wrapper .bx-prev{
 background: url("../Images/arrow_left.png") no-repeat 7px 9px;
 left: 0px;
    }

    .slider .bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover{
 background:  url("../Images/arrow_left.png") no-repeat 8px 15px;
    }

    .slider .bx-wrapper .bx-next{
 background:  url("../Images/arrow_right.png") no-repeat 10px 12px;
 right: 0px;
    }

    .slider .bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover{
 background:  url("../Images/arrow_right.png") no-repeat 10px 17px;
    }

    /*--- End Image Slider --*/

    .one-third img{
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .border_section p{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 padding: 2%;
 color: white;
 text-align: justify;
    }

    .border_section h3
    {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1%;
    }

    .border_section
    {
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: black;
    }

    .one-third {
    width: 27.35%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 0 3% 4%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    }

    .guitarLogo img:hover
    {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;

    }

    footer{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 6%;
 background-color: black;
 overflow: auto;
    }

    footer p
    {
 margin-top: 1%;
 color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="border_section">
            <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/ibanezLogo.jpg" runat="server"/>
  </div>
     </section>
   
        <section class="one-third">
  <div class="border_section">
   <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/fenderLogo.jpg" runat="server"/>
  </div>
     </section>

        <section class="one-third">
  <div class="border_section">
   <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/gibsonLogo.jpg" runat="server"/>
  </div>
     </section>

        <section class="one-third">
  <div class="border_section">
   <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/prsLogo.jpg" runat="server"/>
  </div>
     </section>

        <section class="one-third">
  <div class="border_section">
   <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/ernieballLogo.jpg" runat="server"/>
  </div>
     </section>

        <section class="one-third">
  <div class="border_section">
   <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/espLogo.jpg"    runat="server"/>
  </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Could you maybe make a fiddle?  Also, are you sure it isn't working?  If the background color of an `<img>` element was changed, I feel like it would be hidden behind the image itself....

Comment: It'd be a lot more helpful to post only the relevant CSS instead of all of it

Comment: You cant set background property of an image like this. If you want to make a blue overlay add a div with blue background color which gets faded in on hover.

Comment: Do you mean change the `border-section` background color like this? : https://jsfiddle.net/59drat5e/

Comment: @Wilq - yes thats actually what im talking about. But the problem is, i can't really use border-section because it will affect other images on the other web page that is using the same class. I've tried nesting it with a div tag but its not working.

Comment: If you need to use it only on that elements and not affect others, then add a new class like `myClass` to the div element around img, and add existing css with :hover to it : https://jsfiddle.net/59drat5e/4/

Comment: @Wilq - Finally got it! This solved it. I seriously didn't thought about changing the class name of div around img.

Comment: Best to keep it simple;) I'll post this as answer. Happy to help

Comment: Have you tried applying CSS filters to the img? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: Also, on line 4 of your html you have a closing `section` tag that has no opening equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to affect other elements and change the background color of `div` element around your images, then create new class like `myHover` and add existing CSS to it, like:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="border_section myHover">
  <img class="guitarLogo" src="../Images/Guitar Brands/fenderLogo.jpg" runat="server" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.myHover:hover {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/59drat5e/4/

Answer (score 1):

The selector would be `img.guitarLogo:hover`

But setting a background-color for an image will only affect the visible part *around* the image (if there is ANY), and `color` would only affect text (and there isn't any), so you will problably see no effect, even if it works.

Comment: Probably no need to increase specificity here by adding an element selector. `.guitarlogo:hover` is probably completely sufficient.

Comment: @connexo yes, true

Comment: @BrunoEarth please read my *whole* answer - you won't see a change for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: Problem already solved at above comments. I just simply changed the div class name wrapped around img tag as advised by Wilq.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS:

```
.guitarLogo img:hover {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;     
}
```

Is incorrect, because the .guitarLogo already targets the `<img>` element - no need for img:hover.

Also, that isn't going to work, because there is no way you can set z-index to background only - it's possible only for elements.

The way to do what you want is to register :hover on parent container and in it by using pseudo element :before / :after as the foreground you can get the desired effect.

Comment: Elements that cannot have content (`img`)  can also not act as a host for pseudo elements.

Comment: Thats why i said parent container. Actually that exact solution is offered already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your css

```
.guitarLogo:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are targeting the wrong element. The `background-color:blue` will only be visible if the image is `transparent`, otherwise most of the time the image will just overlap any background color for it to be visible.

What you should be doing is targetting the container element as shown below.

```
.border_section:hover
{
color: yellow;
background-color: blue;

}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/yaENVx)**

If you have images with transparencies or still if you want to set the `background-color` of the `img` just for the sake of it, then maybe you should write the rule as below.

```
img.guitarLogo:hover
{
color: yellow;
background-color: blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also overlay background color to image

```css
.overlay {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
}
.overlay img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.overlay:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:red;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.overlay:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="" />
</div>
```